# align equations in enumerate

Tags: equations, align, enumerate, aligned

I would like to align equations within an enumerate-environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $3x+5=18$
\item $x=27-39x$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the = aligned to each other. Is there a way to do it automatcally? I am looking for a simple solution, like typing a &. I would like to do it without unhandy solutions like a table. Is there anyway? I also do not like the command eqmakebox.

Comment: You're wanting to have an automatic solution that is easy. That is not always possible. The use of `\eqmathbox` makes the alignment automatic, but requires intervention. You can also place manual `\hphantom`s of the largest left-/right-hand sides everywhere. But that it's automatic.

Comment: @Werner Thanks for you answer. It is realy sad, that it not possible in a easy way. For me as a math teacher it would make my life so much easier to creat tasks with a good layout. Usually task for students are written in Word, I assume that I am one of few middle school teachers to use LaTeX ;)

Comment: Here's a possible approach: Write a new environment that allows you to just place `&` wherever you want alignments. Then you split up the contents of that environment at every `\item` and `&` so you can have a handle on each component (I can't help with this). However, I foresee you suddenly wanting automated double alignments (two equations), or work with nested lists, or have some other restriction that builds on this... (La)TeX generates beautiful output, but you sometimes have to code to make it work.